# Can I force boost to prefer forward slashes on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, boost

question is basically as stated in the title.

I am using an API that needs forward slashes regardless of OS (don't shoot the messenger, I don't think this is good practice either). Is there a way to force `boost::filesystem::path`'s member function `make_preferred()` always use forward slashes as default even on a windows machine?

If not, is there a more efficient method than just straight up replacing every `\\` with `/`?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178714/what-is-the-difference-between-pathstring-and-pathgeneric-string-in-boos?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much! Although I don't like the answer's tone. A good teacher doesn't tersely respond to questions "it's in the book," although that phrase might appear in a good answer. There's too much documentation out there to expect every developer to grasp all of it.